# Mockito - How to mock equality?

Tags: java, mockito

I have the below conditional statement which I need to mock. Is it possible to mock this using mockito?

```
if (events.size() == rowsAffected) {
// app logic
}
```

Here the `events` are of type `List<Map<String, Object>>` which will be returned from a function.

`rowsAffected` is of type `int` which will also be returned by a method.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> events = service.getEvents();
int rowsAffected = service.updateEventStatus(events);
```

Comment: Do you need that the mocked method evaluates the condition and perform something?

Comment: Thats right @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 0):

When you need to mock a method with custom behavior, you can use [`answer`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html). Example:

```
public class MockMe {
    public String hello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}

@Test
public void testCase() {
    List<Map<String, Object>> events = service.getEvents();
    int rowsAffected = service.updateEventStatus(events);
    Answer<String> myMockedAnswer = invocation -> {
        if (events.size() == rowsAffected) {
            return "mock good";
        }
        return "mock bad";
    };
    MockMe mockMe = mock(mockMe);
    doAnswer(myMockedAnswer)
        .when(mockMe).hello(anyString());
    assertEquals("mock good", mockMe.hello("anything"));
}
```