# Mockito doesn't support mocking equals(). What are the workarounds?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

Here's a class that I want to test. Basically, I want to ensure that `findApplicationDoc()` returns whatever the `WebClient` does (you are free to consider it silly)

```java
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.swaggerDocParser.SwaggerDocParser;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * An {@link ApplicationDocClient} implementation for finding Swagger (Open API) documentation exposed by {@link DiscoverableApplication}s
 */
@Getter
public class SwaggerClient implements ApplicationDocClient<SwaggerParseResult> {
    private final String scheme;
    private final String docPath;
    private final WebClient webClient;
    private final SwaggerDocParser parser;

    SwaggerClient(SwaggerClientConfigurer configurer) {
        this.scheme = configurer.getScheme();
        this.docPath = configurer.getDocPath();
        this.webClient = configurer.getWebClient();
        this.parser = configurer.getParser();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SwaggerParseResult> findApplicationDoc(DiscoverableApplication application) {
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri(scheme + application.getName() + docPath)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(parser::parse);
    }
}
```

Here's a test (it's mostly setting up mocks):

```java
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.discoverableApplication.DiscoverableApplication;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.swaggerDocParser.SwaggerDocParser;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

class SwaggerClientTest {
    @Test
    void testFindApplicationDoc() {
        DiscoverableApplication discoverableApplicationMock = mock(DiscoverableApplication.class);
        when(discoverableApplicationMock.getName()).thenReturn("test-application");

        String testScheme = "test://";
        String testDocPath = "/doc";

        SwaggerDocParser parserMock = mock(SwaggerDocParser.class);

        SwaggerParseResult parseResultMock = mock(SwaggerParseResult.class);
        when(parseResultMock.equals(parseResultMock)).thenReturn(true); // note this line

        WebClient webClientMock = mock(WebClient.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(webClientMock
                .get()
                .uri(testScheme + discoverableApplicationMock.getName() + testDocPath)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(parserMock::parse)
        ).thenReturn(Mono.just(parseResultMock));

        SwaggerClientConfigurer swaggerClientConfigurerMock = mock(SwaggerClientConfigurer.class);
        when(swaggerClientConfigurerMock.getWebClient()).thenReturn(webClientMock);
        when(swaggerClientConfigurerMock.getDocPath()).thenReturn(testDocPath);
        when(swaggerClientConfigurerMock.getScheme()).thenReturn(testScheme);
        when(swaggerClientConfigurerMock.getParser()).thenReturn(parserMock);

        SwaggerClient swaggerClient = new SwaggerClient(swaggerClientConfigurerMock);
        Mono<SwaggerParseResult> applicationDoc = swaggerClient.findApplicationDoc(discoverableApplicationMock);
        StepVerifier.create(applicationDoc)
                .expectNext(parseResultMock)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
}
```

Sadly, it doesn't work. The problem is Mockito refuses to mock `equals()` for a `SwaggerParseResult` mock (or any `equals()`, for that matter). `equals()` is invoked in that `StepVerifier` method chain since it has an `expectNext()` call

Using `Answer`, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70308295/23299948) in this answer, didn't help

```java
        SwaggerParseResult parseResultMock = mock(SwaggerParseResult.class);
        doAnswer(invocation -> true).when(parseResultMock).equals(parseResultMock);
```

Now, it seems, I'm forced to either manually create and pass a *real* `SwaggerParseResult` (I did it, and I didn't enjoy it) or mock a ton of Swagger-related types and their getters, such as ones of `OpenAPI`, `Paths`, `PathItem`, `Operation`, etc. so that the `equals()` call returns the correct result

What do you recommend as a workaround?

Comment: Also, why does Mockito have that limitation? I meant to include this question in the original post, but then figured you'd close it for being unfocused